# Forwarding DNS request

Tags: networking, openwrt, forwarding

i have OpenWRT and i already setup a hotspot.
i want redirect DNS Request from client to other DNS Server i have using a iptables

here the iptables

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp -s 192.168.1.17 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to DNSServerIP:533
```

But my client got `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET`.

[image: Chrome error screen]

Comment: `--to-destination`. Also have you also done `SNAT`/`MASQUERADE` for `192.168.1.17` at the interface towards `DNSServerIP`?

Comment: i don't have SNAT for 192.168.1.17

Comment: Not even for `192.168.1.0/24` generally (`/24` assumed) or everything going out the WAN interface? It's hard to tell without the whole picture of the firewall. Also what's DNSServerIP? (I mean like is it a remote host outside the LAN or what.) And why `533`? (I mean, is it really listening on `533`?)

Comment: yes 192.168.1.0/24 out interface is WAN, DNSServerIP is external Server and on DNSServerIP:533 i have setting for DNS Filtering

and DNSServerIP is a IP Public